# startActivity(intent) method call expected error

Tags: java, android

If put the following code in dialog, an error occurs

If put the following code in dialog, an error occurs

If put the following code in dialog, an error occurs

CustomDialog.java

```
        public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {
        @BindView(R.id.dialog_button_app_quit) TextView quit;
        @BindView(R.id.dialog_button_app_quit_review) TextView review;
        @BindView(R.id.adView) AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_native_ad);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(request);

    quit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        }
    });

        review.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.xxxx.packageName"));
            startActivity(intent()); <----- error

        }
    });
```

Comment: are you try startActivity(intent) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `intent` not `intent()`
change  `startActivity(intent());` to  `startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 2):

Please change the code with the below one.

```
 review.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.xxxx.packageName"));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: thankyou.but used this, get this error "cannot resolve method startActivity(android.content.Intent);" I uploaded the all code.plese look at

Comment: Is that a custom dialog class? or an activity?

Comment: custom dialog class

Comment: You need to add context to the constructor of the custom dialog class. and then use that context as context.startActivity(intent);